# Website made in react, requests don't work when tested in proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, proxy, nest

I have a react app with Vite, and consumption of a node/nestjs api.

When I try to test my site in proxies (any proxy) the requests do not work and they return a 404 error on the console

Proxy site for testing: [ProxySite](https://www.proxysite.com/)

React app: [App](https://dreamy-druid-4bfd07.netlify.app)

ViteConfig:

```
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => ({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgr(),
    tsconfigPaths()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx']
  },
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://test-cms-api.herokuapp.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
}))
```

Server side config:

```
app.use(cookieParser(jwtSecret));
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

  //Handler de erros
  app.use(
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    (err: Error, request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      handleError(err, response);
    },
  );

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: jwtSecret,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new session.MemoryStore(),
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        signed: true,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      },
    }),
  );
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  app.enableCors({
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ['Authorization'],
  });

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api/');

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      exceptionFactory: validationExceptionFactory,
    }),
  );

  process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && Swagger({ app });
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

I expected my site to work with any type of proxy. Previously I used react scripts for build and the screen didn't even render. With Vite this was solved but now the requests don't work

Comment: I don't get it. What do you need these proxies for?

Comment: the potential customer uses proxies in all accesses